# How to change Icon of collapse and expand?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

My code is below and I want to change icon up and down when collapse and expand is done. But somehow it's not working.

```
<div class="attach-link">

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" *ngIf="fileData.fileDataType.canAttach && !isFinancialEntity" (click)="openFileInput(i)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Attachment</a>
                <input type="file" class="hide" id="fileData_{{i}}" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="fileData.uploader" (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected()"
                />
                <a class="attachFileList" href="#attachFileList_{{i}}" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-up" ></i>                       

                    Attachments [{{fileData.fileList.length}}] </a>
            </div>
```

And added script :

```
 $('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function () {            
        //$(this).find('i').addClass('fa fa-angle-up').removeClass('fa fa-angle-down');
        $(this).find('i .fa fa-angle-up').toggleClass('fa fa-angle-down');
    });
```

I don't know what is the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: *ngIf is looking inside of your component for the collapse property. If it doesn't exist or you're not toggling it, the icon won't change. Add a collapse property to your component and a function that toggles its value. Add a click handler to your link that expands the list that calls the function to toggle the collapse property.

Comment: Still it's not working.

Comment: why are you using jquery in angular

Comment: you only need to add  <a (click)="collapse=!collapse" class="attachFileList" href="#attachFileList_{{i}}" data-toggle="collapse"> content </a>

Comment: @SharmaVikram, Yeah thanks it works fine. But it expand in all listitems. How can I resolve this?

Comment: can you show what show response in of listitems. then i will implement or explain brefily. it will easy for me

Comment: @SharmaVikram, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HQZbYJ6ko_j-whmz3hVa8hpFbZYrIh_-/view Look this.

Comment: ok your data is in loop right, can you provide sample response and please upvote my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170124/discussion-between-srusti-thakkar-and-sharma-vikram).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the sample code of collapse up and down in angular.

```
<div class="attach-link">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);"  (click)="openFileInput(i)">
              <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Attachment</a>
            <input type="file" class="hide" id="fileData_{{i}}" ng2FileSelect (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected()"
            />
             <br>                
            <a (click)="collapse=!collapse" class="attachFileList" href="#attachFileList_{{i}}" data-toggle="collapse">
                <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-angle-up': collapse, 'fa-angle-down': !collapse}"></i>    
                Attachments {{fileData.fileList.length}}                 
            </a>
 </div>
```

> Controller

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  collapse:boolean =true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @sharma-vikram answer, if someone wants to fix the expand-collapse issue above explained, **for more then one element** in a loop, this can be done as below.
Obs.: that's a simple solution, not using ngbCollapse or material.

Template (html):

```
...
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col" (click)="toggle(rowItem)" >
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-plus': rowItem.classList.contains('d-none'), 'fa-minus': !rowItem.classList.contains('d-none')}"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" #rowItem>
    Value
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller (ts):

```
...
public toggle( element: HTMLElement) {
  element.classList.toggle('d-none');
}
```

Comment: What error? Does it say 'classList' is undefined? What browser are you using? IE9 doesn't support classList property

Comment: In *.ts* I have code like                                                                                                     
  ```toggle(item, index) {
    let selector = `.row-num-${index}`;

    let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.row-num');

    document.querySelector(selector).classList.toggle('d-none');

  }```  so here should I use  **element.classList.toggle('d-none');** again?

Comment: Please also tell  in ```valores.classList.contains('d-none')``` what is valores?

Comment: oops...it's supposed to be 'rowItem', instead of 'valores'...I just fixed it, thanks

Comment: it´s not possible to see what´s wrong in your code, unless you post your template html; I suggest you to write another question on SOF, posting both, ts and html, so we can check what is wrong